pyside6-deploy failed with an exception
I am trying to make a standalone pyside6 app with some machine-learning features like Yolo.
Everything runs in a virtual environment.
Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Python 3.8.10
I am building the app for Ubuntu only, but I plan to deploy it for Windows as well.
Please see the command line output.
Also, the command took a very long time to complete(~3 hours)
Command : (tensorflow_env) navaneeth@ramakrishnann-u-det:~/workspace/OMS/action_detection/standalone_app/Qt-App-4-deploy$ pyside6-deploy mainwindow.py
Collecting nuitka==1.8.0
  Using cached Nuitka-1.8-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting ordered-set>=4.1.0 (from nuitka==1.8.0)
  Using cached ordered_set-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.3 kB)
Collecting zstandard>=0.15 (from nuitka==1.8.0)
  Using cached zstandard-0.23.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Using cached ordered_set-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Using cached zstandard-0.23.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (5.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: zstandard, ordered-set, nuitka
  Attempting uninstall: zstandard
    Found existing installation: zstandard 0.23.0
    Uninstalling zstandard-0.23.0:
      Successfully uninstalled zstandard-0.23.0
  Attempting uninstall: ordered-set
    Found existing installation: ordered-set 4.1.0
    Uninstalling ordered-set-4.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled ordered-set-4.1.0
  Attempting uninstall: nuitka
    Found existing installation: Nuitka 1.8
    Uninstalling Nuitka-1.8:
      Successfully uninstalled Nuitka-1.8
Successfully installed nuitka-1.8 ordered-set-4.1.0 zstandard-0.23.0

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.0 -> 24.2
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: anti-bloat: Undesirable import of 'setuptools' (intending to avoid 'setuptools') in 'triton.common.build' (at
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: '/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/triton/common/build.py:10') encountered. It may slow down compilation.
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING:     Complex topic! More information can be found at https://nuitka.net/info/unwanted-module.html
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: anti-bloat: Undesirable import of 'unittest' (intending to avoid 'unittest') in 'torch._dynamo.testing' (at                           
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: '/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_dynamo/testing.py:10') encountered. It may slow down compilation.
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING:     Complex topic! More information can be found at https://nuitka.net/info/unwanted-module.html
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: anti-bloat: Undesirable import of 'IPython' (intending to avoid 'IPython') in 'ultralytics.utils.checks' (at
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: '/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/utils/checks.py:574') encountered. It may slow down compilation.
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING:     Complex topic! More information can be found at https://nuitka.net/info/unwanted-module.html
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: anti-bloat: Undesirable import of 'IPython' (intending to avoid 'IPython') in 'ultralytics.utils.checks' (at
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: '/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ultralytics/utils/checks.py:574') encountered. It may slow down compilation.
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING:     Complex topic! More information can be found at https://nuitka.net/info/unwanted-module.html
{standard input}: Assembler messages:                                                                                                                                      
{standard input}:48541: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
{standard input}:49639: Error: number of operands mismatch for `jmp'
{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
gcc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1
compilation terminated.                               
scons: *** [module.yt_dlp.extractor.lazy_extractors.o] Error 1
[DEPLOY] Exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/scripts/deploy_lib/commands.py", line 24, in run_command
    subprocess.check_call(command, shell=is_windows)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/bin/python', '-m', 'nuitka', '/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/action_detection/standalone_app/Qt-App-4-deploy/mainwindow.py', '--follow-imports', '--onefile', '--enable-plugin=pyside6', '--output-dir=/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/action_detection/standalone_app/Qt-App-4-deploy/deployment', '--quiet', '--noinclude-qt-translations', '--linux-icon=/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/scripts/deploy_lib/pyside_icon.jpg']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/scripts/deploy.py", line 102, in main
    command_str = python.create_executable(source_file=config.source_file,
  File "/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/scripts/deploy_lib/python_helper.py", line 200, in create_executable
    command_str = self.nuitka.create_executable(source_file=source_file,
  File "/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/scripts/deploy_lib/nuitka_helper.py", line 65, in create_executable
    command_str, _ = run_command(command=command, dry_run=dry_run)
  File "/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/scripts/deploy_lib/commands.py", line 30, in run_command
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: [DEPLOY] Command /home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/bin/python -m nuitka /home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/action_detection/standalone_app/Qt-App-4-deploy/mainwindow.py --follow-imports --onefile --enable-plugin=pyside6 --output-dir=/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/action_detection/standalone_app/Qt-App-4-deploy/deployment --quiet --noinclude-qt-translations --linux-icon=/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/scripts/deploy_lib/pyside_icon.jpg failed with error Command '['/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/bin/python', '-m', 'nuitka', '/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/action_detection/standalone_app/Qt-App-4-deploy/mainwindow.py', '--follow-imports', '--onefile', '--enable-plugin=pyside6', '--output-dir=/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/action_detection/standalone_app/Qt-App-4-deploy/deployment', '--quiet', '--noinclude-qt-translations', '--linux-icon=/home/navaneeth/workspace/OMS/tensorflow_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PySide6/scripts/deploy_lib/pyside_icon.jpg']' returned non-zero exit status 1. and return_code1


This could be due to low system resources since gcc was killed, check available memory using, 'free -h' and try,
sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab

This creates a 4GB swap file.
Also ensure proper gcc toolchain,
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential gcc g++ libstdc++6

try updating nuitka as well,
pip install --upgrade nuitka

